# Mailer in Rails Issue - Views Not Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am new to mailers in rails. I have deployed to heroku and the emails are sending and being received fine. The issue is that none of the mailers are rendering the views.

That was not always the case. I must have moved something vital to that connection and broke the connection. Can you tell me how to reconnect the views to the mailer?

I am on rails 3.2 and here is the information you may need to answer:

In the invitation model:

```
after_create do |invitation|
   InvitationMailer.delay.invitation_email(self)
end
```

And in mailers:

```
class InvitationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  helper ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
 default from: "noreply@lumeo.com"

 def invitation_email(invite)
   @invitation = invite

   mail(to: invite.recipient_email, 
    subject: "Invitation",
    :template_path => 'mailers/invitation_email')
 end
end
```

And finally, the view is located at views/mailers:

```
You are invited to join our beta!

    <%= link_to 'Sign Up', signup_with_token_url(@invitation.token) %>
```

This line is routed correctly and is working as I have tested it in the past, but the view is no longer rendered in the body of the email...

Dev Logs:

```
Started POST "/invitations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-04 17:00:22 -0800
Processing by InvitationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SwmmoRObXNI5PoXYhGFc4zsqLulSJ4iq0v9VbcRBJ3E=", "invitation"=>{"recipient_email"=>"brian@labyrinth.com"}, "commit"=>"Send Invite"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'brian@labyrinth.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "invitation_limit" = 6, "updated_at" = '2012-11-05 01:00:22.236722' WHERE "users"."id" = 2
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "invitations" ("created_at", "recipient_email", "sender_id", "sent_at", "token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 05 Nov 2012 01:00:22 UTC +00:00], ["recipient_email", "brian@labyrinth.com"], ["sender_id", 2], ["sent_at", nil], ["token", "650e4773e64a1120355e5392ecfea2fefb47dabf"], ["updated_at", Mon, 05 Nov 2012 01:00:22 UTC +00:00]]

Sent mail to brian@labyrinth.com (917ms)
Date: Sun, 04 Nov 2012 17:00:22 -0800
From: noreply@lumeo.com
To: brian@labyrinth.com
Message-ID: <50970fa63e33c_6673fd1a1035ae061987@Retina.local.mail>
Subject: Invitation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/invitations
Completed 302 Found in 942ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)


Started GET "/invitations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-04 17:00:23 -0800
Processing by InvitationsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  Invitation Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" 
  Rendered invitations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (4.7ms)
  Image Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."parent_id" = 2 AND "images"."parent_type" = 'User' LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "roles"."id" = "assignments"."role_id" WHERE "assignments"."user_id" = 2
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (9.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 26.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Heroku Logs:

```
 2012-11-05T01:09:21+00:00 app[web.2]: Started POST "/invitations" for 76.175.198.239 at       2012-11-05 01:09:21 +0000
 2012-11-05T01:09:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:4ba7555d-5659-4f95-a8fb-13326b458480 pid:2)] Starting job worker
2012-11-05T01:09:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-11-05T01:09:22+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:4ba7555d-5659-4f95-a8fb-13326b458480 pid:2)] New Relic Ruby Agent Monitoring DJ worker host:4ba7555d-5659-4f95-a8fb-13326b458480 pid:2
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by InvitationsController#create as HTML
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Utls4PaX/7TkwyZkhZnkm3pf8llGoX/j5LskL+9rO40=", "invitation"=>{"recipient_email"=>"brian@labyrinthvisuals.com"}, "commit"=>"Send Invite"}
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4528 LIMIT 1
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:    (3.2ms)  BEGIN
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (3.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'brian@labyrinthvisuals.com' LIMIT 1
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:    (0.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "invitation_limit" = 90, "updated_at" = '2012-11-05 01:09:21.797013' WHERE "users"."id" = 4528
 2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:   SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "invitations" ("created_at", "recipient_email", "sender_id", "sent_at", "token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Mon, 05 Nov 2012 01:09:21 UTC +00:00], ["recipient_email", "brian@labyrinthvisuals.com"], ["sender_id", 4528], ["sent_at", nil], ["token", "53e21931e3481036c9019f8245e518b5ce8343aa"], ["updated_at", Mon, 05 Nov 2012 01:09:21 UTC +00:00]]
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Sent mail to brian@labyrinthvisuals.com (886ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Date: Mon, 05 Nov 2012 01:09:22 +0000
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: From: noreply@lumeo.com
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: To: brian@labyrinthvisuals.com
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Message-ID: <509711c25d54a_2fc899c84342@52b7b88c-4573-408e-8219-a12f9c4087fb.mail>
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Subject: Invitation
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:  charset=UTF-8
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 heroku[router]: POST www.lumeo.com/invitations dyno=web.2 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1857ms status=302 bytes=98
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]:    (3.7ms)  COMMIT
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Redirected to http://www.lumeo.com/invitations
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 302 Found in 1543ms (ActiveRecord: 22.2ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: 
2012-11-05T01:09:23+00:00 app[web.2]: Started GET "/invitations" for 76.175.198.239 at    2012-11-05 01:09:23 +0000
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 heroku[router]: GET www.lumeo.com/invitations dyno=web.2 queue=0 wait=0ms service=727ms status=200 bytes=8052
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Role Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "assignments" ON "roles"."id" = "assignments"."role_id" WHERE "assignments"."user_id" = 4528
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (544.9ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4528 LIMIT 1
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Invitation Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" 
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]: Processing by InvitationsController#index as HTML
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered invitations/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb (0.8ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Image Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "images".* FROM "images" WHERE "images"."parent_id" = 4528 AND "images"."parent_type" = 'User' LIMIT 1
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.3ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]: Completed 200 OK in 708ms (Views: 664.3ms | ActiveRecord: 39.2ms)
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:59079
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/05/12 01:09:23 +0000 1a2f3028-d8e6-415a-889a-de99cac2c096 (2)] INFO : Dispatcher: thin
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/05/12 01:09:23 +0000 1a2f3028-d8e6-415a-889a-de99cac2c096 (2)] INFO : Application: sharp-flower-5688
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/05/12 01:09:23 +0000 1a2f3028-d8e6-415a-889a-de99cac2c096 (2)] INFO : New Relic Ruby Agent 3.4.1 Initialized: pid = 2
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.1]: ** [NewRelic][11/05/12 01:09:24 +0000 1a2f3028-d8e6-415a-889a-de99cac2c096 (2)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler sampler not available: No DJ worker present
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]: Connected to NewRelic Service at collector-5.newrelic.com
2012-11-05T01:09:24+00:00 app[web.2]: ** [NewRelic][11/05/12 01:09:24 +0000 52b7b88c-4573-408e-8219-a12f9c4087fb (2)] INFO : Reporting performance data every 60 seconds.
```

Please help. These are some of the last things I need to do before I launch publicly...tomorrow...

Comment: Are you perhaps relying on a layout for your emails? Then you'd need to include `layout: <your email layout name>`. Also, it would be helpful if you could include the log output of your email being sent, and what's actually received. "without view" isn't really clear.

Comment: Well then look at the [layout section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts) of the guide :) but if you've never used one, that's probably not your issue here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. No. I am not using layouts.

Comment: First step in debugging this is to skip the delay and deliver the mail  directly: `InvitationMailer.invitation_email(self).deliver` - then you'll have the full mail content in your logfiles. Post that output.

Comment: Updated per your instructions, Thilo, and posted the logs.

Comment: Strange - it should show more than just the "Sent mail" line. That should be followed by the headers and content. Are you using `:debug` log level?

Comment: Probably not, but I will look that up. In the meantime, I posted the dev logs that show more information.

Comment: Your email's content type is set to text/plain. That's the issue I think.

Comment: Okay. Not sure how to apply the information. Where and how can I set that?

Comment: Brian you need to wrap your email view in HTML headers.. like a standard HTML file. with body tags, etc.

Comment: what's the path for your html/text views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view will not render if the file name or path is incorrect.

In this case, you should have:

```
app/views/invitation_mailer/invitation_email.text.erb
```

and if you want html also:

```
app/views/invitation_mailer/invitation_email.html.erb
```

You shouldn't have to set :template_path

Comment: Thanks. Just figured this one out, same answer.

Comment: darn, beat me to it by a few seconds :)